# How to make a Paypal form with user options

Tags: html, css, paypal

I'm trying to create a Paypal page so visitors of my site only have to click on a link which will take them to a Paypal checkout.

What I need to do is for it just to have some basic options such as:

- Allowing the user to enter their name
- Allowing the user to enter their weight
- Etc

I went on the Paypal website and I managed to get the button which allows the visitors to pay but I need a form so the visitor can enter the options. How do I get the form so they can?

Comment: I think you may need to rephrase your question, or at least improve upon the spelling/grammar. I could be in the minority here, but your question and what you want to accomplish is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Cart Upload Command](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/) method of [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) as opposed to the PayPal generated buttons.

You can build your form(s) however you want and then pass that data into the PayPal form accordingly as hidden fields.  You can refer to the [Standard variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) for details on what all you can include, which does include item options and selections.